# Dynamics 365: Javascript retrieveRecord function to retrieve value and name from lookup field

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

I use retrieveRecord function to retrieve lookup values from a lookup and then assign the values to other lookup fields.

```
 var result = Xrm.WebApi.retrieveRecord(sellTo[0].entityType, customerId, '?$select=name,_kk_paymentterms_value,_kk_shippingmethod_value,_kk_freightterms_value');
        paymentTerms = result._kk_paymentterms_value;
        shippingMethod = result._kk_shippingmethod_value;
        freightTerms = result._kk_freightterms_value;
```

I need names to set values to lookup fields, how can I retrieve them?

Comment: didn't you select names in your query? `?$select=name, ...`

Comment: I try to use multiple times expand parameter to get values from multiple lookups but I get error.
I use something like this:
Xrm.WebApi.retrieveRecord(sellTo[0].entityType, customerId, '?$select=name,&$expand=kk_PaymentTerms($select=kk_name,kk_transactionalcodeid),&$expand=kk_FreightTerms($select=kk_name,kk_transactionalcodeid)');
But when I use only one expand, it works as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a **Prefer** header value to your request:

```
GET [Organization URI]/api/data/v9.2/contacts?$top=100
&$select=fullname,_parentcustomerid_value,statuscode,createdon
&$filter=firstname eq 'henk' and lastname eq 'boeijen' and _parentcustomerid_value ne null

Accept: application/json  
OData-MaxVersion: 4.0  
OData-Version: 4.0
Prefer: odata.include-annotations="OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue"
```

Now the (localized) display values are added to the response for options, booleans, lookups, dates etc.

```json
{
  "@odata.context": "[Organization URI]/api/data/v9.2.23084.206/$metadata#contacts(fullname,_parentcustomerid_value,statuscode,createdon)",
  "value": [
    {
      "@odata.etag": "W/\"831620324\"",
      "fullname": "Boeijen, Henk van",
      "_parentcustomerid_value@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue": "My Company Name",
      "_parentcustomerid_value": "d96679fb-0e61-ed11-9561-0022487fe2b5",
      "statuscode@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue": "Active",
      "statuscode": 1,
      "createdon@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue": "28-10-2022 11:17",
      "createdon": "2022-10-28T09:17:55Z",
      "contactid": "e8ef9664-a152-ed11-bba1-0022487feed1"
    }
  ]
}
```

See also [Query data using the Web API: Formatted values - MS Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/webapi/query-data-web-api#formatted-values).